# How to list all the proprietary drivers / stuffs installed on Ubuntu Mate 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, ubuntu-mate, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I am again playing / trying to benchmark (to measure the temperature more exactly) my Ubuntu Mate 16.04, that runs on my 10 yr old (2009) laptop that runs on Intel P8700 CPU and ATI Radeon 3670.

I am asking this, so it may help to shed some lights and also help other Linux noobs like me.

1. I installed an Ubuntu Mate 16.04.06 without the proprietary drivers checked (u know, there is a checkbox option (the one described with 'MP3 drivers from Fraunhover blabla) for that during early phases of the install using the GUI installer, just before the partition selection, iirc).

With this option, I was unable to play any MP3 files using the Rhytmbox, but I can play MP3s using VLC thou.

2. I installed another Ubuntu Mate 16.04.06 on another partition with the proprietary drivers checked.

With this option I was able to play MP3s using Rhytmbox. I also believe that Mozilla Firefox also installs the Flash Plugin with this option.

---

I was looking to find out what propritary drivers/softwares installed on the 2nd partition. I opened `System -> Administraion -> Software & Updates`, opened the `Additional Drivers` tab-- that says `No Proprietary Drivers are in use`.

This https://itsfoss.com/install-additional-drivers-ubuntu/ is the best info/ref I could find.

I am quite confused now. How come there are no additional proprietary drivers installed on the 2nd partition ??

Is there any other ways to check ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

That checkbox is not about proprietary DRIVERS, but proprietary audio/video codecs and Adobe Flash. There was no need to re-install the system to add them.

You could install `ubuntu-restricted-addons` package to get those.

So the output that no proprietary drivers are installed is correct.

Comment: Ok, thx. So is there any way to list all those proprietary stuffs? Like I want to know what are the (all ) the differences installed ?

Comment: It is a different story to ask about drivers or stuffs. I don't know a simple way to list all that.

Comment: I am a noob dude... I can only do `sudo apt install blabla`... and also maybe install from Synaptic..

Comment: So `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` installs these "stuffs"

Comment: `apt search ubuntu-restricted-extras` ? Only `ubuntu-restricted-addons` is installed. `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is not installed.

Comment: You can explore dependencies e.g. in Synaptic and see what is the difference. I think that the `extras` installs a bit more proprietary "stuffs". I always install it.

Comment: Ok. I will check them later. I am gonna sleep now. Thx